# Why is the set $C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:v(\{x\})\neq 0\}$ countable, where $v$ is a finite measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading a book on measure theory by Donald Cohn, and on page 132 the author states after the proof of Lebesgue decomposition theorem that:

> One sometimes goes a step further for a finite measure $v$ on
> $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Let
> $C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:v(\{x\})\neq 0\}$, and note that $C$ is countable
> (for each positive integer $n$, there are only finitely many points
> $x$ such that $v(\{x\})\geq 1/n$).

It is not immediately clear to me why the set $C$ is countable, unless $C=\emptyset$. **So my question is:** Why is $C$ countable if $C\neq \emptyset$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v(\{x_1\},v(\{x_2\},...,v(\{x_n\} >\frac  1 k$ where $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are distinct then $v(\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\} >\frac n k$. This cannot happen if $\frac n k >v(\mathbb R)$. Hence there are only a finite number of points $x$ such that $v(\{x\} >\frac  1 k$. This is true for each $k$. The union of these countable sets over $k=1,2...$ is countable and this union is exactly $\{x: v(\{x\}) >0\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @KaboMurphy, got it now, I should have taken into account the finite nature of $v$.